# Any benefit to using streams if all the data fits in a single chunk?

Tags: node.js, stream

When I do `fs.createReadStream` in Node.js, the data seems to come in 64KB chunks (I assume this varies between computers).

Let's say I'm piping a read stream through a series of transformations (which each operate on a single chunk) and then finally piping it to a write stream to save it to disk...

If I know in advance that the files I'm working on are guaranteed to be less than 64KB each (ie, they'll each be read in a single chunk), is there any benefit to using streams, as opposed to plain old async code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you can configure the chunk size using [the `highWaterMark` parameter](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_readable_options): it defaults to 16k for byte-mode streams (16 objects for object-mode streams), but `fs.ReadStream` default to 64k chunks (see [relevant source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.10/lib/fs.js#L1419-L1422)).

If you are absolutely sure that your all of your data fits in a single chunk, there is no immediate benefit to using streams, indeed.

But remember that streams are flexible; they are the unifying abstraction of your code: you can read data from a file, a socket or a random generator. You can add or remove a duplex stream from a streams pipeline and your code will still work in the same way.

You can also pipe a single readable stream into multiple writable streams, which would be a pain to do using only asynchronous callback…

Also note that streams don't emit data synchronously (i.e. the `readable` event is emitted on the next tick), which handles nicely for you the common mistake to synchronously call an asynchronous callback, thus creating a possible stack overflow bug.

Comment: Additional point is that while YOUR chunk is 16k, 64k or whatever, the recipient of the stream might be smaller - and for them it would be beneficial to be streaming anyway.